# Android Firebase User Creation

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication

On my signup activity I'm unable to register to firebase and move to the next activity. I've checked the console and can see the account doesn't exist either and from the Logcat - it isn't particularly helpful. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the signup_activity

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
LinearLayout facebookLinearLayout, twitterLinearLayout, googlePlusLinearLayout;
Button registerButton;
ImageView bgImageView;
Button forgotButton;
EditText mUsername, mEmail, mPassword;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    initUI();
    initDataBindings();
    initActions();

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

//region Init Functions
private void initUI() {

    forgotButton = findViewById(R.id.forgotButton);

    facebookLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.facebookLinearLayout);
    twitterLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.twitterLinearLayout);
    googlePlusLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.googlePlusLinearLayout);
    registerButton = findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    bgImageView = findViewById(R.id.bgImageView);
    mUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}

private void initDataBindings() {
    int id = R.drawable.lightbg;
    Utils.setImageToImageView(getApplicationContext(), bgImageView, id);
}

private void initActions() {
    forgotButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Forgot Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    facebookLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Facebook - Not available just yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    twitterLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Twitter - Not available just yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    googlePlusLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Google Plus - Not available just yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

    //assign database instances
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth){
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null) {
            }
            else{
                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = mUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            mUsername.setError("Please provide a Username");
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmail.setError("Email Required");
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            mPassword.setError("Password Required");
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            mPassword.setError("Password must be greater than 6 characters");
            return;
        }
        //Register the user
        fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Error!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    });
    //endregion
}
```

And the activity should both register within Firebase and move to the dashboard

public class FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_dashboard_news_dashboard1);

    initData();

    initUI();

    initDataBinding();

    initActions();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked "+ item.getTitle() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void initData() {

}

private void initUI() {

    // Init Toolbar
    initToolbar();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homeMenu:
                loadFragment(new FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment());
                break;
        }

        return true;
    });

    loadFragment(new FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment());

}

private void initDataBinding() {

}

private void initActions() {

}

private void initToolbar() {

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.baseline_menu_black_24);

    if (toolbar.getNavigationIcon() != null) {
        toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

    toolbar.setTitle("News Dashboard 1");

    try {
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_white_1000));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Can't set color.");
    }

    try {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Error in set support action bar.");
    }

    try {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TEAMPS", "Error in set display home as up enabled.");
    }

}

private void loadFragment(FeatureDashboardNewsDashboard1Fragment fragment) {
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `onclickListener` on your `registerButton` twice with one being empty.

Remove the first `onclickListener` (which is in your oncreate) and I think it would solve the problem.

Comment: fantastic, feel like a right idiot for missing that but thank you so much for a fresh set of eyes. it doesn't move onto the next activity but I'll now try to figure that out. it isn't letting me accept the answer yet either but I will once it lets me.